# Listing elemets of a list as i want, in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

This is my list in Prolog:

```
myList([a,b,c,d,e]).
```

I am trying to write a predicate. That predicate should give me this result:

```
ab
ac
ad
ae
bc
bd
be
cd
ce
de
```

I found a solution that's near to my goal. But it is not exactly what I want.

```
?- L=[a,b,c], findall(foo(X,Y), (member(X,L),member(Y,L)), R).

L = [a, b, c],

R = [foo(a, a), foo(a, b), foo(a, c), foo(b, a), foo(b, b), foo(b, c), foo(c, a), foo(c, b), foo(..., ...)].
```

For example i dont want to aa or bb or cc. Also, there is already ac result. So i dont want to again ca.

Sorry for my English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
   true.
?- List = "abcde",
   bagof(X-Y, Pre^Ys^( append(Pre, [X|Ys], List), member(Y,Ys) ), XYs).
   List = "abcde", XYs = [a-b,a-c,a-d,a-e,b-c,b-d,b-e,c-d,c-e,d-e].
?- List = [A,B,C,D,E],
   bagof(X-Y, Pre^Ys^( append(Pre, [X|Ys], List), member(Y,Ys) ), XYs).
   List = [A,B,C,D,E], XYs = [A-B,A-C,A-D,A-E,B-C,B-D,B-E,C-D,C-E,D-E].
```

From your question it is not that evident what you want but it seems you are happy to use `findall/3`.  Above solutions use `bagof/3` which is a somewhat more civilized version of `findall/3`. `bagof/3` takes into account variables, and thus you get the same result with concrete characters `[a,b,c,d,e]` or with a list of variables `[A,B,C,D,E]`.

You have used terms `foo(a,b)`, in such situations it is more common (and convenient) to say `a-b`.

Comment: Elegant, elegant. I have allowed myself to steal this in order to add a note at the findall page of SWI Prolog doc.

Comment: Also, the printout of `XYs` will be truncated unless `set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options, [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(100)]).`

Comment: I agree with these two indentations, but not with the max depth, nor the other SWI-related links. SWI does not even implement `bagof/3` nor `findall/3` correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but any more info on the wrong implementation of bagof/findall for SWI Prolog? Or, in which implementation are they correct?

Comment: SICStus is fine. Whereas in SWI, `findall(t,(repeat,fail),1)` should produce a `type_error(list,1)` but it rather loops.

Comment: And `max_depth(0)` is my setting for SICStus

Comment: @David: As for elegance, please refer to the other answer. This here loops for problematic cases (which is still much better than having incorrect answers).

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution that does not need any of the higher-order predicates.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
:- use_module(library(double_quotes)).

list_pairwise([], []).
list_pairwise([E|Es], Fs0) :-
   phrase(values_key(Es, E), Fs0,Fs),
   list_pairwise(Es, Fs).

values_key([], _K) --> [].
values_key([V|Vs], K) -->
   [K-V],
   values_key(Vs, K).

?- list_pairwise("abcde", KVs).
   KVs = [a-b,a-c,a-d,a-e,b-c,b-d,b-e,c-d,c-e,d-e].
?- list_pairwise(L, [a-b,a-c,a-d,a-e,b-c,b-d,b-e,c-d,c-e,d-e]).
   L = "abcde"
;  false.
?- list_pairwise(L, [A-B,A-C,A-D,A-E,B-C,B-D,B-E,C-D,C-E,D-E]).
   L = [A,B,C,D,E]
;  false.
?- KVs = [K1-_,K1-_,K2-_|_], dif(K1,K2), list_pairwise(Ks,KVs).
   KVs = [K1-K2,K1-_A,K2-_A], Ks = [K1,K2,_A], dif:dif(K1,K2)
;  false.
```

In the last query we show that a sequence starting with keys, `K1, K1, K2` can only result in the sequence of three elements.

Answer (score 1):

What about a couple of predicates as follows ?

```
printCouples(_, []).
printCouples(E1, [E2 | T]) :-
  write(E1), write(E2), nl,
  printCouples(E1, T).

printList([]).
printList([H | T]) :-
  printCouples(H, T),
  printList(T).
```

From

```
printList([a, b, c, d])
```

you get

```
ab
ac
ad
bc
bd
cd
```

Comment: The 3 answers worked fine. I used this one because i understood that codes easily.